Maximum distance between two points of a polyhedron
Given a (bounded and feasible) polyhedron, $P=\{x\mid Ax\le b\}$ and a number $\gamma > 0$, decide if there are two points $x, y \in P$ such that $\Vert x - y\Vert_p \ge \gamma$.

Is there an $\ell_p$ norm for which the above problem is poly-time solvable?
Is there an $\ell_p$ norm for which the above is $NP$-hard?

If yes, can the maximum distance between any two points be approximated in poly-time? ($\max \Vert x - y\Vert_p$ s.t. $x, y \in P$)
Alternatively, can (provably) good-quality upper bounds be computed for this problem in poly-time?




The maximum distance between points in the polytope is called diameter (terminology note: ^1), or inner 1-radii (times two) [2] of the polytope $P$.
A closely related problem is the norm maximization problem of computing $\max_{x \in P'} \|x\|_p$.
If $P'$ is centrally symmetric i.e. $P' = -P'$, then the diameter is twice the maximum norm. Conversely, let $P' = P - P = \{x_1 - x_2 \mid x_1, x_2 \in P\}$ then $P'$ is centrally symmetric and the maximized norm on $P'$ is equal to the diameter of $P$.
For $p = \infty$, the problem is polynomial-time solvable by trying all the dimensions. Solve $\max_{x \in P} x_i$ and $\min_{x \in P} x_i$ for every $i$ and take the maximum difference.
For every $1 \leq p < \infty$, maximizing the $L^p$-norm, and therefore computing the diameter, is NP-hard [1] [2].
For every $2 \leq p < \infty$, the problem doesn't have a polynomial-time constant-factor approximation algorithm unless P=NP [3].
^1: In literature, a different measure of a polytope is also simply called diameter (diameter of the unweighted graph of 1-skeleton), not to be confused.

[1]: Bodlaender, Hans L., et al. "Computational complexity of norm-maximization." Combinatorica 10 (1990): 203-225.
[2]: Gritzmann, Peter, and Victor Klee. "Computational complexity of inner and outer j-radii of polytopes in finite-dimensional normed spaces." Mathematical programming 59.1 (1993): 163-213.
[3]: Brieden. "Geometric Optimization Problems Likely Not Contained in APX." Discrete & Computational Geometry 28 (2002): 201-209.


For $p=1$ is any approximation known?

@LisaE. I couldn't find results on the p=1 approximation case.
